# Stop Dev app server in windows?

Tags: google-app-engine, dev-appserver

How to stop Dev app server in windows when I am trying to run my GAE as a web application on local server it shows port in use and giving error.

Comment: Use a different port or terminate the existing one with the task manager.

Comment: You may want to review this article https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments to specify a different port.